# Specify variable types in Javascript (for parsing purposes)

Tags: javascript

I am building an automated documentation tool for a work and I am facing some issues when searching some method references. Dynamic variables are of type "any" and their methods cannot be parsed (trying to access the definition in Visual Studio will typically result in "cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret").

More context with an example: In my source code, I am targeting every references of a "Query" method (used for AJAX calls), it is a method defined in the "Step" class. But my problem is that dynamically set variables are of type "Any" and their properties does not refer to anything: the ".Query()" method in "step.Query()" does not refere anything in particular because step is of type "any" and not "Step".

I was wondering if it is possible to enforce a type to dynamically set variables, in order to solve this issue. I know that typescript typically handle this kind of things, but if there is a way to do it in JavaScript directly that would be excellent.

Comment: JavaScript has no facility for declaring a data type for variables, parameters, or object properties. Any variable (etc) can be assigned a value of any type.

Comment: You could use `instanceof`, but your mileage may vary... But you should really use Typescript for stuff like this `let step = new Step(); ... if(step instanceof Step) { ... }`

Comment: @Pointy This would mean that it is technically impossible to parse non-static methods/properties in a JavaScript source code ?

Comment: @Pierre In some cases it might be possible to perform some static analysis, but that's a complicated process

Comment: @Pointy This is what I've done by using TypeScript and the ts-morph library to parse my raw Javascript scipts. It is indeed quite complex but it does the job for the static analysis part.

Hard-coded checks can somehow manage some non-static analysis (for the example I've given: looking up for any PropertyAccessExpression having a right identifier named "Query"). But that far from optimal.

Comment: TypeScript is a completely different story than JavaScript; static type declaration and inference is the whole point.